# Отображать определённую часть текста в TEdit

Tags: delphi

Есть TEdit, в него вводится текст и когда длина текста превышает ширину этого TEdit, то что было введено вначале уходит за левую границу поля ввода.
Как сделать, чтобы при вводе длинного текста в TEdit было видно то, что умещается по ширине, а то что вводится далее уходило за правую границу и не двигало текст влево?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что используете: VCL или FMX?

Comment: Я использую VCL

Comment: У меня складывается ощущение, что не получится сделать то, что вы хотите. У однострочного элемента позиция курсора всегда видна. Можно после потери фокуса передвигать курсор в начало текста, тогда произойдёт прокрутка влево до упора, но во время ввода не получится.

Comment: К тому же склоняюсь. Что задумка не реализуема.